# How to catch an element from a for loop in Django template?

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I'm looping through to different categories and rendering results (of its name and its associated pages). This code is rendering correctly.

```
{% for category in categories %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3><a href="{{category.get_absolute_url}}"></a>{{category.category_name}}</h3>
        {% for page in category.page_set.all %}
        <p><a href="{{page.get_absolute_url}}">{{page.page_title}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to catch an specific element inside the for loop (to be precise the 4th one in the forloop counter) and customize it (adding some html and text only to that one). I tried using the `forloop.counter` like this:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
    <!-- modified content -->
{% endif %}
```

But there isn't any results (not showing any changes). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question. You can try it soo:
You can place this inside your for loop so that whenever you it iterates and by that you can use your if value to do some operations for specific value.

```
{% if some_variable == some_value %}
    {{ do_something }}
{% endif %}
```